# Getting the userAgent from Android phones

Tags: php, android, laravel

I'm setting a new PHP server, I'm trying to get the user agent from all requests to the server.

```
    $client = new Client;
    $client->userAgent= $request->userAgent();
    $client->save();
```

When accessing the server from browser the User agent is correct, while when 
I send a request from Android application I get the name of the library used to send the request "okhttp/3.14.1"

what should I do to get it right?

Comment: If this is your Android app, then probably you can change User-agent, when sending these requests. If not, then you can treat `okhttp/3.14.1` as Android device at your server

Answer (score -1):

You can get the request agent using $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']